# Target element if it is the first element inside a div

Tags: css, css-selectors

Given the following, is there a way to target an element ONLY if it is an h3 AND it is positioned immediately inside the parent?

```
 <style>
   h3:first-of-type { color: #f00; }
 </style>
```

Example a)

```
<div class="mydiv">
   <h3 class="tobetargeted"></h3>
</div>
```

Example b)

```
<div class="mydiv">
   <p></p>
   <h3 class="nottobetargeted"></h3>
</div>
```

Neither first-of-type or first-child will work because in both cases, the h3 element evaluates to true. What I want is for Example a) to be true but Example b) to be false.

So... IF the element is an H3 AND it is the first element immediately inside the parent.

Any ideas?

Comment: How can the h3 match :first-child in your second example?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`:first-child` should definitely work out for you.

```css
.test {
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: 0 0 10px;
}
.test h3:first-child {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="test">
  <h3>H3 - should be red</h3>
</div>
<div class="test">
  <p>p</p>
  <h3>H3 - should be black</h3>
</div>
```

Comment: Your test is flawed. An h3 cannot be nested within a p. The reason it's not matching in that last example is not because the h3 is not a child of .test - it is, in fact, the second child of .test. Having said that, you're right in that :first-child should work.

Comment: I used the direct descendant selector for that reason (`>`) otherwise it would've been selected as well (since it's a first child of `<p>`).

Comment: The direct descendant combinator is irrelevant. Try selecting it using `p>h3` and tell me if you still think it's a child of the p.

Comment: Okay just tried - you're right. The rest of the answer is still correct though, imo, so I'll edit out the `<p>` part.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback :) I had no idea `h3`s can't be inside `p`s

Answer (score 1):

Use this

```
h3:nth-child(1) { color: #f00; }
```

```css
h3:nth-child(1) { color: #f00; }
```

```html
<div class="mydiv">
   <h3 class="tobetargeted">Hello</h3>
</div>
<div class="mydiv">
   <p></p>
   <h3 class="nottobetargeted">Hello</h3>
</div>
```